# Connect to 4D database with database client

Tags: database, 4d-database

I have developed an application using 4D database. But I want to connect any database client to my 4D database for querying the tables (in which I am comfortable of).

I know that I can use sql in 4D database too but my requirement here is to query the 4D database tables with database client because in 4D I have to store the values obtained from query into variables/listview.

Is this possible?  If yes, then how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 4D Client

You could (obviously) use the native 4D Client to connect to 4D Server.

#### 4D ODBC

You could use ODBC to connect to 4D Server from a generic client.

You would need to install the [4D ODBC Driver](http://doc.4d.com/4Dv15R3/4D/15-R3/4D-ODBC-Driver.100-2814232.en.html) appropriate to your environment on the client machine. Remember to match the version of ODBC Driver to the version of 4D and the architecture of the ODBC Driver with the architecture of the ODBC Client.

For example, if your 4D Server is running v15.2 and the generic client is running in 64 bit mode, you would then want to use the [4D v15.2 ODBC Driver 64 bit](http://download.4d.com/Products/Current/4D_v15_2/Installers/ODBC/Windows/4D_ODBC_Driver_v15_2_Windows_64-bit.exe)

On the other hand if 4D Server is running 14.5 and the generic client is running in 32 bit mode, you would want to install the [4D v14.5 ODBC Driver 32 bit](http://download.4d.com/Products/Current/4D_v14_5/Installers/ODBC/Windows/4D_ODBC_Driver_v14_5_Windows_32-bit.exe)

The ODBC Drivers can be downloaded from http://4d.com/downloads/products.html

#### 4D Native SQL Protocol

The 4D SQL Protocol is documented at [Github - 4D/SQLlib_4D](https://github.com/4D/SQLlib_4D) and also on [sources.4d.com](http://sources.4d.com/trac/4d_pdo4d/raw-attachment/wiki/WikiStart/SQL%20networking%20protocol.doc) so theoretically you could write a native connector of some sort.

Comment: Thanks, 4D ODBC works as per my requirement. I installed the 4D ODBC Driver and use RazorSql as client which connect to 4D database via ODBC driver.